# How should I describe this limiting operation in an equation

Tags: notation, vectors, article-writing

In the code I've written, I receive a delta between two position vectors, I then limit this delta by a maximum delta and return the value. To be clear: the direction of the vector remains the same, only the length changes.

*I'm not well versed in mathematics, so my explanation and title may not clearly describe the problem to a mathematician, feel free to improve my text.*

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "limit". Do you mean that you fix the length of the vector to a given amount and keep its direction?

Comment: @A.P. Yes, indeed.

Comment: While "bound" the length will sound a little better to the mathematician's ear than "limit", such operations do occur often in numerical methods.  A compromise might be to say "limit the step size" or "bound the maximum delta", putting the operational word into a closer context with its object.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for the suggestion! My text is in dutch though, where I think it does sound correct (limiteren). Bounding (begrenzen) could work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by delta between two vector you mean their difference. Then the operation you are describing is called *normalization* of the resulting difference. In symbols, you could write it as
$$
\frac{v_2 - v_1}{\| v_2 - v_1 \|}
$$
where $v_2 - v_1$ is the difference between the vectors $v_2$ and $v_1$, and $\| \cdot \|$ denotes the *norm* (i.e. length) of a vector. The result will have norm $1$ and you can rescale it simply by multiplying it by the desired length.

Comment: I ended up writing it as $v = \operatorname{min}(\lVert \Delta \rVert, \Delta \text{max}) \frac{\Delta}{\lVert \Delta \rVert}$ where $\Delta = v_1 - v_0$. Thanks again!

Comment: It is *normalization* to scale the vector to length 1, but here the goal is only to "limit" the vector's length.  If the "delta" vector does not exceed a specified length, it is left unchanged.